# How do I use enums in TSQL without hard coding magic number all over my SQL scripts/procs?

Tags: c#, t-sql, enums

We have enums in our C# code:

```
public enum JobStatus
{        
  Ready = 0,      
  Running = 1,        
  Cancelling = 2,
}
```

These values are also stored in database fields, and we have **lots** of TSQL (mostly stored procs, as well as some batches and SSIS) that also processes the data:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @JobSID = JobSID
FROM Job 
WHERE Status = 0 /* JobStatus.Ready */
ORDER BY SubmitDate ASC

CREATE TABLE ImportCrossEffect(
    /* lots deleted */      
    Source tinyint 
      DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL -- 0: Unknown (default), 1:Imported, 2:Keyed
)
```

**How do I avoid hard coding the “magic numbers” in the TSQL?**
**How do I remove the risk of the enumerations not matching on the C# and TSQL sides?**

(I have included the C# tag, as I would like solution that “single sourced”  the definitions of the enums on both the C# and TSQL sides)

---

**Updates:**

We don't have tables in the database with the Enum names in them, the values are just stored in tiny int columns.

I was hoping for something like a SQL pre-processor that would "expand" all the enum to there "magic value".

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I do like the ideal of using a view, as the view could be generated by the build scrips and it is always easy to update views in a database.

Answer (score 7):

You can always pass the value from the enumeration into the stored proc/command that you are trying to execute.  This way, you never have to worry about the enumerations in the database.

If you want to store the enumerations in the database, then I suggest you create a view (possibly titled with your enumeration), like so:

```
create view JobStatus
    select 0 as Ready, 1 as Running, 2 as Cancelling
```

You can then access/join on the view if you need it to.

Note, the query optimizer treats any reference to the above as a constant scan/scalar operation, not a table scan, so you aren't incurring the reads that would occur if you were accessing an actual table.

Comment: For a handful of values, it's trivial to create the table & populate it.

Comment: Thanks, this may work well for most TSQL, any ideals on how to remove the magic numbers from the default values of columns?

Answer (score 1):

In one project we defined an attribute that applied to every enum member that stored the table and value expected in the database and the unit tests verified the link. Messy though.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use table valued functions for this. They work well with encapsulating and packaging variables together, almost like named enums from other languages.

Let's say we a couple of variables for different order statuses:

- New = 100
- In progress = 250
- Completed = 500

What I would do is create a function that returns my variables

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.OrderStatus()
RETURNS @T_def TABLE 
(
    NEW int,
    IN_PROGRESS int,
    COMPLETED int
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @T_def (NEW, IN_PROGRESS, COMPLETED)
        VALUES (100, 250, 500);
    RETURN 
END
```

I can now use my variables in my queries, and even intellisence will work to hint me about the variables:

```
SELECT
    OrderStatus.NEW
FROM dbo.OrderStatus() "OrderStatus";
```

Or as part of another query using CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT
    OrderStatus.NEW
   ,*
FROM CUSTOMER_ORDERS
CROSS APPLY dbo.OrderStatus() "OrderStatus";
```

Comment: This still dose not give compine time checking of the SQL

Answer (score 0):

In pure TSQL the only similar thing I can think is a scalar UDF that returns the vale wanted.

In LINQ to SQL you can map members as c#/.NET enums, and it handles it for you.

But to be honest; in most pure TSQL I'd mainly just use the literals.

Comment: Thanks, I have been told that  "scalar UDF" are slow, I don't know if this is true

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could implement managed code on the SQL server instead of using normal TSQL?  Not 100% sure if this would work, but it might be an option to explore.

[Possible Solution here...](http://forum.strataframe.net/Topic10664-14-1.aspx)